# Why is testem reporting all the tests as a single test?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, testem

I have multiple passing tests, but everything is reported as a single test.

This is a Node app, it never runs in the browser.

Output

> 1..1
>
> tests 1
>
> pass  1

Testem config:

```
module.exports = {
  src_files: [
    'test/**/*.js'
  ],
  launchers: {
    Node: {
      command: './node_modules/.bin/mocha'
    }
  },
  launch_in_ci: ['Node'],
  launch_in_dev: ['Node'],
};
```

Mocha opts:

```
--recursive
--bail
--sort
--full-trace
--no-timeouts
--ui bdd
--colors
--exit
```

Repro: https://github.com/givanse/testem-mocha-repro

Comment: I'm thinking maybe Mocha is reporting in a way that Testem doesn't understand? But that would be so odd because Testem has supported Mocha for a long time already.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you have to specify the reporter and protocol in the Testem config like this:

```
  launchers: {
    Node: {
      command: './node_modules/.bin/mocha -R tap',
      protocol: 'tap'
    }
  },
```